# Get stuck when importing gensim in Django views.py

Tags: python, django, gensim

FYI, when I try to import gensim module in Django views.py, my server just got stuck, all my restful apis don't not working, not 5**, not 4**, not 3**, not 2**, just no response.

But if I just comment `import gensim` in views.py, it just back to the normal.

So where is the problem, and how to debug Django in this situation?

Django version: 1.8   Gensim version: 0.12.3

### UPDATE

I can import gensim in Django shell
[image]

And same issue on Django 1.9

Comment: Open a Django shell, `import gensim` and tell us what happens...

Comment: Does any code in views.py use `gensim`? If so, can you post the code?

Comment: No, I just encounter this issue when trying to import gensim, and get stuck here.